# How to combine two identical jQuery functions?

Tags: jquery

I have two jQuery functions that are identical:

```
$(".link_scroll").click(function(event){

  // Do stuff...

});

$('a[href=#top]').click(function(){

  // Do the same exact stuff...

});
```

How can I combine the two so I'm not repeating code and making the size of my file larger than it needs to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comma separated:

```
$("a[href=#top], .link_scroll").click(function() {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pull out your function, then attach each one separately to that function:

```
function doSomething(e) {
}

$(".link_scroll").click(doSomething);
$('a[href=#top]').click(doSomething);
```

The `click` function just accepts a function, doesn't matter whether it's an inline function or a named one.